# Summation of determinants

Tags: matrices, determinant

Really struggling with some proofs on matrices, could anyone help here:

> For two $2\times2$ matrices $A$ and $B$, show that if 
>   $\det(A+B) = 0 = \det(A-B) $
>   then
>   $$\det(A) + \det(B) =0$$ is true.

I understand the basic thing around determinants of matrices like $\det AB = \det A \times \det B$ but wasn't really to sure on how to approach this question.

Comment: Welcome back. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I understand the basic thing around determinants of matrices like detAB = detA x detB but wasn't really to sure on how to approach this question.

Answer (score 1):

$$\det(A+B)=0$$ it's
$$\det(A)+\det(B)+a_{11}b_{22}+b_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}b_{12}-b_{21}a_{12}=0$$ and
$$\det(A-B)=0$$ it's
$$\det(A)+\det(B)-a_{11}b_{22}-b_{11}a_{22}+a_{21}b_{12}+b_{21}a_{12}=0,$$ which after summing gives that you want.